# Site color theming with CSS Custom Properties and @media

Tags: css, logic, media-queries, themes, css-variables

The popular direction in allowing for light/dark theme switching is by using CSS Custom Properties. It is most common to simply create a toggle on the page to select light or dark. I'm interested in adding a layer of complexity that allows the user to select the system preference OR an override (of light or dark). Selecting the system preference would then read light and dark at the `@media` level. Unless the user hasn't selected a color-scheme, in which case we'll default to some scheme (let's say light).

Assuming the overrides are set by applying attributes to `document.documentElement`.

- `html[theme="light"]` should *always* provide the light theme even if the user's system is set to dark or not set.
- `html[theme="dark"]` should *always* provide the dark theme, even if the user's system is set to light or not set.
- `html[theme="none"]` should look at the system preferences and determine...

  - `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` should provide the dark theme.
  - `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)` should provide the light theme.
  - `@media (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)` should provide the default, light theme.

The challenge here is that I want to see if I can write the variables for the light/dark themes **once** as it seems every solution I can think of requires a set of variables to be written in two rulesets.

Looking for a native CSS solution here, as I could do this with build tools; SASS `@mixin` code below.

```
@mixin dark-theme() {
  --bg-color: black;
}

:root {
  --bg-color: white;
}

html[theme="dark"] {
  @include dark-theme(); /* 1st occurrence */
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html:not([theme="light"]) {
    @include dark-theme(); /* 2nd occurrence */
  }
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

I'm expecting some sort of combination using `:not([theme])` and `@media not all and (prefers-color-scheme)` but I've tried a few combinations and have gotten close but not 100% of the logic above. I've also tried switching the specific theme for the fallback (setting the dark theme at the `:root` and then attempting to generalize in the `@media` rules to apply the light theme) but that didn't seem to work either.

Ah, no JavaScript solutions either please. Again, looking to see if native CSS is possible.

Comment: So you are trying to reduce the declarations to a minimum, is that right? From my understanding, you won't be able to avoid having two rulesets: within your media query, and outside of it (since they cannot be mixed). Is there a reason you're trying to accomplish this? (not saying that having DRY code is bad, but for one variable declaration, it doesn't feel like a big crime)

Comment: It's not one var, it's an entire theme worth. That's why I'm trying to keep DRY.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well in the grand scheme of things, even with ten or twenty variables, your code will still be pretty clean; this is a micro-optimisation. You usually get over-the-wire compression anyways so it's a negligible performance hit (if any), in my humble opinion (I might be wrong).

Comment: I'm just afraid that for each variable assignment I modify, I'll need to do it twice.

Comment: You already have your `dark-theme()` mixin to populate it in the duplicated spots. Seems like you have all you need.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of doing this natively.

Comment: I guess you could define each variable as `--*-dark` or `--*-light` and assign the `--*` variable based on the current theme. This might be a good way to keep it well maintained natively if you don't want to use your Sass mixin.